# Wordcloud in different shapes in R

Tags: r, word-cloud

I have created a wordcloud in R using package "wordcloud".

But It is plotting wordcloud in any random shape. I want wordcloud in circular or Ellipse shape.

Is there any facility provided by R to create wordcloud in different shapes?

Comment: Set the background and text colour both to black and you'll get an eclipse...

Comment: It was a joke, an eclipse is when an object is obscured by another, particularly when the moon obscures the sun and plunges the world into darkness. I think you meant to write ellipse.

Comment: ohh its a typo mistake bro, btw thanks to see mistake I will correct it. but can u give me solution to problem. will help a lot if any help done.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible without writing a new function.

Comment: A new library wordcloud2 exactly does this https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud2/vignettes/wordcloud.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wordcloud does create wordclouds in a circle I believe -- if it doesn't look circular, play around with the scale of the words and their minimum frequency for inclusion. Depending on what your original word dataset is, though, it might be hard to get it into a true wordcloud shape. Here's an example of a wordcloud that is quite dense -- it does ultimately end up looking circular.

http://binfalse.de/2011/08/wordpress-wordcloud-with-r/

Comment: How does the scaling work anyway? I mean, what are the units? I often can't fit many of my bigrams/ngrams.